# Python 3.0 Pandas converters giving syntax error

Tags: python, pandas, converters

I am running Jupyter notebook with Python 3.0 using Pandas to read from an Excel file. I am using a converter to change values in columns i.e. -1 to 1. I keep getting a syntax error in the converters.

```py
import pandas as pd

def convert_adult(cell):
    if cell==-1:
        return 1      
    return cell

df = pd.read_excel("Merged.xlsx", "Sheet1", converters = ['adult_not_activation':convert_adult])
```

return is

```
  File "<ipython-input-17-8eea921e19bb>", line 10
    df = pd.read_excel("Merged.xlsx", "Sheet1", converters = ['adult_not_activation':convert_adult])
                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am in the beginning of my journey in Python and Pandas so I hope my problem is not too trivial to ask. Cheers

Comment: It looks like your are confusing `list` and `dict`. Try to change it in: `{'adult_not_activation':convert_adult}` and take a look to [converters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Answer (score 4):

The error points you to the problem :) You are using a `list` where a `dict` is expected.

```py
df = pd.read_excel("Merged.xlsx", "Sheet1", converters = {'adult_not_activation': convert_adult})
```

Answer (score 0):

`converters` argument takes a **`dictionary`**, You are giving this `dictionary` as a `list` but with `dictionary` syntax.

```
df = pd.read_excel("Merged.xlsx", "Sheet1", converters = {'adult_not_activation':convert_adult}) # {} instead of []
```